# Script trigger does not fire function

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script with a simple task ("ABC" shown on code) to copy cells values from a sheet and paste it in another one every day at an exact time (18:00 or 6:00 pm). The first part of the script ("setTrigger", "scheduledTrigger" and "deleteTriggers") runs smoothly. I've set an installable trigger to run the script ("setTrigger") every day from 13:00 (01:00pm) to 14:00 (02:00pm). So between 13:00 and 14:00 "setTrigger"fires and create the trigger for "ABC" to fire at 18:00.

The problem is that the script creates a trigger to run the task ("ABC") at 18:00 but when the time comes the trigger is not fired and the task is never done.
If I set an installable trigger to run "ABC", it fires and the task is done, but when the script creates the same trigger, the "ABC" somehow is never fired and the task is never done.

Please help me.

```
function setTrigger() {
  Logger.log('Set ran!');

deleteTriggers();  
scheduledTrigger(18,00);
}

function scheduledTrigger(hours,minutes){
  Logger.log('Schedule ran!');
  
var today_D = new Date();
var year = today_D.getFullYear();
var month = today_D.getMonth();
var day = today_D.getDate();
  
pars = [year,month,day,hours,minutes];
  
var scheduled_D = new Date(...pars);
var hours_remain=Math.abs(scheduled_D - today_D) / 36e5;
ScriptApp.newTrigger("ABC")
.timeBased()
.after(hours_remain * 60 *60 * 1000)
.create()
}

function deleteTriggers() {
  Logger.log('Delete ran!');
  
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
  if (   triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "ABC") {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
}
}

function ABC() {
  Logger.log('ABC ran!');
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('myid'); \\ sheet id is corret but I prefer to not show it here
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('ACOMPANHAMENTO DIARIO'))
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-3', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  var leo = sheet.createTextFinder(date).findAll().map(r => r.getA1Notation());
  sheet.getRangeList(leo).activate();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('RESUMO'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ACOMPANHAMENTO DIARIO'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('RESUMO!B3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('RESUMO'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 3).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ACOMPANHAMENTO DIARIO'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('RESUMO!E3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('RESUMO'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, -3).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ACOMPANHAMENTO DIARIO'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('RESUMO!B4').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('RESUMO'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 3).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ACOMPANHAMENTO DIARIO'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('RESUMO!E4').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('RESUMO'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ACOMPANHAMENTO DIARIO'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('RESUMO!C4').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

Comment: you can't subtract two Date() objects

Comment: @Cooper, In this line (var hours_remain=Math.abs(scheduled_D - today_D) / 36e5;)?

Comment: Yes, you must use either valueOf() or getTime() to get total milliseconds